# Fetching wrong url on clicking button (laravel ) (email)

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3, mailgun

I have email template for verification of email address of a user.

when user clicks on button ,user's email address is verified.

Previously I was sending the link without wrapping it into button and it was working fine.

But now I have wrapped it into a button and when I click on the button it sends me to some different url looks something like this :

[email.example.com/adasd_fsdfsf.....so on](http://email.example.com/c/eJwVjbkOgzAQBb8GlwgbH7hwlUvpUpF6vT6wAjGBoIi_j6nmFfM0znDFXAskGQ6UU-q1tQiAwokOVLAQhGTSCu4r3sBrzdu3xjyRwQgOlipmXQMWJUVHg2-ZYxR1sWUgo6nYdU3xvc1l-AnSWPgBd9sjKt3NvOmnp76cT797FhDDI_ZkMTusQw0Z8zKXZDxuR_EPNKU1iQ)

blade for email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
       <h2>Please verify your email address</h2>

    <div class="row">
        Thanks for creating an account with the example.com. Please click the   button below to verify your email
        address <br>

        <a  href="{{ URL::to('signup/email/' . $confirmation_code) }}">          <button class="btn-block btn btn-default">verify Email</button></a>            

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Whilst you can reference an external style sheet in an HTML email, nearly all email clients will block this and so you won't get the style anyway. What happens if you do this `<a  href="{{ URL::to('signup/email/' . $confirmation_code) }}">verify Email</a>`?

Comment: @James same thing happens :(

Comment: Also try `{{ url('signup/email/' . $confirmation_code) }}`

Comment: @James nothing  happened

Comment: Don't wrap button with anchors. Style anchor to be like button, or use 'location.href' on buttons click.

Comment: @zgabievi removed buttons still not working :(

Comment: What does your `APP_URL` look like in your `.env` file?

Comment: @James http://example.com

Answer (score 1):

Change your `href` to this:

```
href="/signup/email/{{$confirmation_code}}"
```